# PHP 5.4 development server doesn't recognize mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use the new development server in PHP 5.4. It runs `phpinfo()` just fine but on my site code and also `phpMyAdmin.php` they are throwing the following error:

> Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

They are running through localhost:8000

`php -m`  is showing that mysqlnd is loaded but that maybe not enough.

The OS is Windows 7

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Bob. You need to explain your situation a bit better. What development stack are you running? For example using XAMPP or WAMP or other? "The new development server" - We need to know what that means in order to help.

Comment: @Relequestual: He means the PHP 5.4 Built-in web server: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php This web server is designed for developmental purposes only, and should not be used in production.

Answer (score 12):

`mysqlnd` is the library that can be used since PHP 5.3, instead of `libmysql`, by 3 PHP extensions :

- **`mysql`**, which provides the `mysql_*` functions,
- **`mysqli`**, which provides the `mysqli_*` functons,
- and **`pdo_mysql`**, which allows one to use PDO with a MySQL database.

`mysqlnd` by itself doesn't export any function you can use from your PHP scripts : it only provides MySQL connectivity to those 3 extensions -- which are the ones that export functions you can use.

If you want to use the `mysql_*` functions, you have to **make sure that the `mysql` extension is enabled**, with something that whould look like this in one of the `.ini` files parsed by PHP :

```
extension=mysql.dll
```

As a sidenote : the `mysql_*` functions should not be used anymore, especially for new projects : the `mysql` extension is old, and doesn't allow one to use recent *(well, not that recent anymore, actually)* features of MySQL.

Instead, you should be using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to get the mysql.dll and mysqli.dll files linked in the php.ini. All is working well now.

Answer (score 2):

It's because register_globals is no longer included as of PHP5.4, in earlier versions it was deprecated and you could force it on. The reason is because it would leave huge security gaps for hackers to exploit.

Answer (score 1):

try install missing mysql module

`sudo apt install php-mysqli`

check if `extension=mysql.so` is set in php.ini after installation